# how to prevent Android Firefox browser to resize window when soft keyboard is on

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, firefox

Hello to my fellow developers.

I'm building a web application and I'm having problems with Firefox browser on Android. When I click to a text field, the soft keyboard pops up and it resizes my whole window, destroying my css layout.

I managed to overcome this problem with Android Chrome, with the following script:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = 'viewport';
meta.content = 'width=device-width,height='+window.innerHeight+', initial-scale=1.0';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

However, it seems that Firefox browser is not following the above and keeps resizing my window.

**Please, don't confuse my question with a native android application, I'm talking about a web application, just HTML, CSS, JavaScript**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: not even a single reaction? weird...

Comment: I no longer have that problem with Firefox on android, but still do with Chrome. So your question has an answer to the many unanswered questions I see here on the viewport being resized by the Chrome soft keyboard.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384678/how-to-stop-soft-keyboard-resizing-chrome-browser-window-on-android-mobiles

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```